# As a UK citizen am I entitled to Paternity leave for a child born in Japan?

Tags: united-kingdom, japan

I am a UK citizen, living in the UK, married to a Japanese citizen we are currently going through the Visa application process so she can move to UK.
She will however give birth (in Japan) before this process is finalised, will I be entitled to take paternity leave (paid)?

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE.  This depends on laws of the country where you are.  If by law you're entitled to have paternity leave the location of your child may or may not matter depending on how law is written.  Further in some countries like United States it is a matter of policy of your employer.

Comment: @Karlson: Seems he's in Japan, no?

Comment: @Flimzy Possibly, or he's in the UK already paving the way for his wife's arrival.  There are also a few scenarios that I can describe that are somewhat more far fetched.

Comment: @Karlson: I agree the verbiage is a bit vague, but I think that's the only reasonable thing to assume, considering the tags he chose. Anyone who gave an answer with those assumptions would not be blamed if they missed the mark.

Comment: @Flimzy Sure.  But why not just wait for clarification instead of updating or rewriting an answer?

Comment: Hi, sorry I was not more clear... I am living in UK, my wife is in Japan (once she has had the baby and we get the Visa sorted, she will move to the UK)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking where your child is born doesn't seem to be a concern for the [eligibility for Paternity Leave](https://www.gov.uk/paternity-pay-leave/eligibility).

You can also try to fill out the form [SC3](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/forms/sc3form.htm) for your employer to see if the place or country of birth is actually relevant but it doesn't seem to be.

But you can check further with your employer's HR department to verify the information and other conditions that may have been imposed if any.